# C# Timer resolution: Linux (mono, dotnet core) vs Windows

Tags: c#, linux, timer, mono

I need a timer that fires every 25ms. I've been comparing the default `Timer` implementation between Windows 10 and Linux (Ubuntu Server 16.10 and 12.04) on both the dotnet core runtime and the latest mono-runtime.

There are some differences in the timer precision that I don't quite understand.

I'm using the following piece of code to test the Timer:

```
// inside Main()
        var s = new Stopwatch();
        var offsets = new List<long>();

        const int interval = 25;
        using (var t = new Timer((obj) =>
        {
            offsets.Add(s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            s.Restart();
        }, null, 0, interval))
        {
            s.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }

        foreach(var n in offsets)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(offsets.Average(n => Math.Abs(interval - n)));
```

On windows it's all over the place:

```
...
36
25
36
26
36
5,8875 # <-- average timing error
```

Using dotnet core on linux, it's less all over the place:

```
...
25
30
27
28
27
2.59776536312849 # <-- average timing error
```

But the mono `Timer` is very precise:

```
...
25
25
24
25
25
25
0.33 # <-- average timing error
```

**Edit:** Even on windows, mono still maintains its timing precision:

```
...
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
24
0.31
```

What is causing this difference? Is there a benefit to the way the dotnet core runtime does things compared to mono, that justifies the lost precision?

Comment: 2017 still no actual solution. Why don't someone wrap up native c++ multimedia timer in each platform. Don't know if there're any problem?

Comment: @b.ben I believe it's actually possible to use the mono implementation of the `Timer` class on Windows, in the CLR (without using mono), and you'll get the same precision. The issue here is just the STL implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot rely on timers in the .NET framework. The best one has 15 ms frequency even if you want to trigger it in every millisecond. But you can implement a high-resolution timer with microsec precision, too.

**Note:** This works only when `Stopwatch.IsHighResolution` returns true. In Windows this is true starting with Windows XP; however, I did not test other frameworks.

```
public class HiResTimer
{
    // The number of ticks per one millisecond.
    private static readonly float tickFrequency = 1000f / Stopwatch.Frequency;

    public event EventHandler<HiResTimerElapsedEventArgs> Elapsed;

    private volatile float interval;
    private volatile bool isRunning;

    public HiResTimer() : this(1f)
    {
    }

    public HiResTimer(float interval)
    {
        if (interval < 0f || Single.IsNaN(interval))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(interval));
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    // The interval in milliseconds. Fractions are allowed so 0.001 is one microsecond.
    public float Interval
    {
        get { return interval; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0f || Single.IsNaN(value))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value));
            interval = value;
        }
    }

    public bool Enabled
    {
        set
        {
            if (value)
                Start();
            else
                Stop();
        }
        get { return isRunning; }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (isRunning)
            return;

        isRunning = true;
        Thread thread = new Thread(ExecuteTimer);
        thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        isRunning = false;
    }

    private void ExecuteTimer()
    {
        float nextTrigger = 0f;

        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        while (isRunning)
        {
            float intervalLocal = interval;
            nextTrigger += intervalLocal;
            float elapsed;

            while (true)
            {
                elapsed = ElapsedHiRes(stopwatch);
                float diff = nextTrigger - elapsed;
                if (diff <= 0f)
                    break;

                if (diff < 1f)
                    Thread.SpinWait(10);
                else if (diff < 10f)
                    Thread.SpinWait(100);
                else
                {
                    // By default Sleep(1) lasts about 15.5 ms (if not configured otherwise for the application by WinMM, for example)
                    // so not allowing sleeping under 16 ms. Not sleeping for more than 50 ms so interval changes/stopping can be detected.
                    if (diff >= 16f)
                        Thread.Sleep(diff >= 100f ? 50 : 1);
                    else
                    {
                        Thread.SpinWait(1000);
                        Thread.Sleep(0);
                    }

                    // if we have a larger time to wait, we check if the interval has been changed in the meantime
                    float newInterval = interval;

                    if (intervalLocal != newInterval)
                    {
                        nextTrigger += newInterval - intervalLocal;
                        intervalLocal = newInterval;
                    }
                }

                if (!isRunning)
                    return;
            }


            float delay = elapsed - nextTrigger;
            if (delay >= ignoreElapsedThreshold)
            {
                fallouts += 1;
                continue;
            }

            Elapsed?.Invoke(this, new HiResTimerElapsedEventArgs(delay, fallouts));
            fallouts = 0;

            // restarting the timer in every hour to prevent precision problems
            if (stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalHours >= 1d)
            {
                stopwatch.Restart();
                nextTrigger = 0f;
            }
        }

        stopwatch.Stop();
    }

    private static float ElapsedHiRes(Stopwatch stopwatch)
    {
        return stopwatch.ElapsedTicks * tickFrequency;
    }
}

public class HiResTimerElapsedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public float Delay { get; }

    internal HiResTimerElapsedEventArgs(float delay)
    {
        Delay = delay;
    }
}
```

**Edit 2021:** Using the [latest version](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/blob/master/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/CoreLibraries/HiResTimer.cs) that does not have the issue @hankd mentions in the comments.

Comment: Then how does mono's implementation provide timers with a resolution of ~1ms? And why is the normal .NET framework not using such a solution?

Comment: That's what I cannot tell. IMHO all of the timer implementations should provide that, too (System.Timers.Timer, System.Threading.Timer, System.Windows.Forms.Timer). But if you cannot rely on them beyond a specific precision the question is not why but how you can accomplish your needs.

Comment: Heh. This is strange: you don't even need those tiered Sleep()s. I wrote a quick implementation that has the same precision as the mono-timer on all platforms using just WaitOne: http://pastebin.com/58QbCQVZ

Comment: Well, interesting solution, yet very unusual usage of `WaitOne` considering that your `WaitHandle` is never set (only in `Dispose`). Additionally, it has no sub-millisecond precision. As for the Sleeps: a simple `SpinWait` would be enough for the functionality but it spares the CPU better if there is more time until the next event. Btw, I upvoted you because I found your question interesting.

Comment: It's basically the core of the mono `Timer` implementation. It's using `WaitOne` so that the timer can be stopped instantly when Dispose is called (which would be more useful for larger intervals), or if the interval changes (which I did not implement).

Comment: I don't really need the sub-millisecond precision, so I don't think it'd be worth wasting 1-2ms (which accumulates to 40-80ms per second) on `SpinWait`, which is, if I understand correctly, essentially a `while` loop with a few bells and whistles.

Comment: The Mono implementation uses a separate managed scheduler thread and a `WaitOne` (as @Size43 mentioned) and is a totally different implementation from the MS ref. source that relies on sync objects, Win32 and marshalling.... But ***remember*** that you can not guarantee timing when using managed threads/objects/callbacks... place stress on the .Net/Mono runtimes and your timing will be all over the place...

Comment: Cool timer implementation

Comment: FYI: When I tried this for an interval of 20ms, the accuracy was pretty bad (often having Delays of ~6-7ms). The Thread.Sleep calls seem to be the culprit, replacing those with other Thread.SpinWait calls fixed the issue.

Comment: @hankd: The `diff < 15f` line is not quite correct because by default `Thread.Sleep(1)` takes about 15.5ms. I actually fixed this in my libraries recently, which is not released yet but [here](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/blob/2c85322e5fcbaa89dc245e459ae32f10f2c1e405/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/CoreLibraries/HiResTimer.cs#L221) is the actual version that should work correctly.

Comment: @Size43 I can't reproduce your results with WaitOne on .NET 5, FYI.  Resolution seems to be ~15ms for me.