# Smooth animations in c# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, animation

I want to show an animation frame by frame (picture by picture) in a pictureBox. I have 42 frames and I want to make it really fast. I have used the Timer component but interval = 1 milisecond is too slow and I wanted to know if there is any way to make a fast animation with a lot of frames in c# Windows Forms (Visual Studio). This is what I'm using right now

```
    Bitmap[] FelixBanner = new Bitmap[50];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for(int i = 1; i <= 42; i++)
            FelixBanner[i] = new Bitmap(@"Photos\Felix\" + i + "FB.bmp");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    int k = 1;

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (k == 41) 
            timer1.Enabled = false;

        Felix.Image = FelixBanner[k];
        k++;
    }
```

Comment: The interval is 1 milisecond

Comment: That's should be really fast, try to change pictures from different thread

Comment: The Timer component in WinForms is driven by the Windows message pump. You can expect timer intervals to be much larger than 1ms. Probably, your WinForms timer is not suitable for timing animations, because it's not reliable enough.

Comment: Additionally, to all the timer inaccuracy, do you understand that the human visible system is not able to recognize more than around 1 picture every 35-45 milliseconds? you know, that stuff make movies "movies", not images.

Comment: Okay :)). I just don't know how to make smooth animations. I'm new to this.

Comment: Winforms will simply not let you create smooth animation without diving into hardware issue to synch it with the monitor refresh. Sorry.

Comment: @TaW C'mon :) Yes, it can. Are you still stuck on a FW < 7.1? [Imgur](https://imgur.com/Q053vkB) -- Image frames taken from: [Gyphy](https://giphy.com/gifs/l4FGvLcn2VZFmJrVK) (the images frames have been extracted to single PNG files. 68 images, 480x480, 400kb each)

Comment: _FW < 7.1_  Um, meaning what? - Btw: The animation looks quite choppy to me. Instead of such complicated thing how about a ball moving along an line, slowly but smoothly.

Comment: @TaW 7.1+ The Framework and the PictureBox work better, both handling manually the Image Animator  class and when it renders animated GIFs on its own (for example, you can have multiple Animations running at the same time with different intervals per frame - all render smoothly). -- The animation posted to Imgur *may* not look perfect because Gif Animator (what I use to create the animations) has its limitations. I provided the original Image so you can disassemble it and test it yourself. I used a standard Timer to loop the frames.

Comment: @ TaW If you're referring to hardware sync when animating shapes, then of course it cannot do that. But you can generate a sequence of Images where you paint a ball that moves half a pixel per frame.

Comment: @TaW  [This one](https://imgur.com/RwiTEhE) is taken at 24 frames per seconds. It should give a better idea of the possible results. In the meanwhile, the Form is perfectly functional, of course. It wouldn't matter if it wasn't. BTW, the label `Frames per sec` is wrong: that's the Timer Interval, not the frames/sec ratio (I forgot to change the text :).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, none of the built-in timers have 1 ms precision. I do not repeat or copy-paste an [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41697139/5114784) of mine but see the link for a high-precision timer. Or see the full source at [GitHub](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/blob/master/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/CoreLibraries/HiResTimer.cs).

Secondly, using a `PictureBox` control for custom rendering is an overkill. Unless you utilize zoom/stretch capabilities, or assign an animated GIF to it, you don't need it at all. It is much more effective to render your animation in a simple `Panel`, using the `Paint` event for example. This is how you can do it:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    if (k == 41) 
        timer1.Enabled = false;

    //Felix.Image = FelixBanner[k];
    k++;
    panelAnimation.Invalidate();
}

void panelAnimation_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // make sure "k" is a valid index even after playing the animation because the
    // Paint event might be called whenever your form is resized or has to be repaint
    var image = FelixBanner[k];
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
}
```

Comment: Okay. I've added Panel panelAnimation= new Panel(); and the code that you wrote but It doesn't show anything. I press the button and nothing happenes. And I never used Panels before so I'm sorry if this is really basic.

Comment: A PictureBox has DoubleBuffering enabled by default, the Panel doesn't (having DoubleBuffering active is an advantage, here). The reasoning behind *overkill* is undefined. For the rest it'll work. To remember, the  [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer) resolution can't be less than ~`35ms` (the events may overlap otherwise), but, *officially*, values below `55ms` are not supported. It **can** provide a flow of 24/25 frames per second, though, value that make a well-built animation smooth to the human eye.

Comment: @RobertGaube: You need to add the panel to the form. Just drop it on the form from the toolbox in the designer (it will be named `panel1` by default).

Comment: @Jimi: You are right, I didn't elaborate '_overkill_'. I meant that `PictureBox` is basically not for replacing its image repeatedly. Setting the `Image` property causes a `PerformLayout` call in the parent control, checks whether the new value can be animated, etc. A `PictureBox` is handy if you don't want to always manually repaint the invalidated area, to play GIF animations automatically and to allow some simple scaling using the `SizeMode` property.

Comment: Well, yes, setting the PictureBox.Image can cause Layout events if the SizeMode (AutoSize, Zoom, Stretch) instructs the Control to resize the Image to its ClientSize. But if the Image Size doesn't change, the Layout events are only generated a couple of times. On the other hand, when the Image property is set and then the Image rendered, a number of other procedures are initialized. The Control also needs to verify whether a new Image should be animated and so on. Drawing the Image directly on its surface using its Graphics object doesn't require internal initialization procedures.