# stopwatch in .NetMaui is not accurate

Tags: xamarin, time, stopwatch, .net-maui

Hi The stopwatch that I have made is not accurate(millisecond precision) - it is slow. How can I change that? I also would like to make timer counting down. There is literally no tutorials or any information how to do that. Do you have any solutions? Do you know any useful videos or internet pages?

MainPage

```
    <StackLayout 
    VerticalOptions="Center">
    
    <Label 
        x:Name="timeLable"
        Text="0:000"
        TextColor="White"
        FontSize="Header"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>

    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                 HorizontalOptions="Center"
                 Spacing="12"
                 Margin="0,60,0,0">

        <Button
            x:Name="startStopButton"
            BackgroundColor="Black"
            Clicked="OnStartStop"
            WidthRequest="60"
            HeightRequest="60"/>


        <Button
            x:Name="reset"
            BackgroundColor="Black"
            WidthRequest="60"
            Clicked="OnReset"
            HeightRequest="60"/>

    </StackLayout>

</StackLayout>
```

MainPage.cs

```
    public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private TimeOnly time = new();
private bool isRunning;

private async void OnStartStop(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    
    isRunning = !isRunning;

    while (isRunning)
    {
        time = time.Add(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
        SetTime();
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
    }
}


private void SetTime()
{
    timeLable.Text = $"{time.Second}:{time.Millisecond:000}";
}


private void OnReset(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    time = new TimeOnly();
    SetTime();
}
```

Comment: “Not accurate” is not a helpful description of the problem.  .NET has multiple timer classes in System.Timers

Comment: I see no [`Stopwatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch) in your implementation. Do you mean your `Task.Delay(1)` usage? Unfortunately it will never work accurately. If you want millisecond precision with a timer you need to use a [custom one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41696144/5114784).

Comment: Have you tried to deploy or release it to see if work accurately?

Comment: Yes I tried to release it, but it is to slow . Currently I have no time to make a better one but in this weekend I will try to do new one.